# Usage of my classes in JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have got a little Problem. I have the classes: FXScreen, GeometricObject, Vertext,Play and  Gapplication.
My task is to take them and make a JavaFX Project, so the rectangles will be shown in a Gui. But I cant find any solution. I have created a JavaFX project and got the new class Main.java and the css File named application.
Cant find any Tutorial about this. Please help me with any Idea. Here are the mentioned classes:

FXScreen:

```
package application;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public class FXScreen extends Canvas {
GeometricObject[] geos;

public FXScreen(GeometricObject[] geos) {
this.geos = geos;
this.setWidth(200);
this.setHeight(600);

setFocusTraversable(true);
GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
for (GeometricObject geo:geos){
  geo.paintMeTo(gc);
}

timer.start();
}

AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
@Override
public void handle(long l) {
  setFocused(true);

  for (GeometricObject geo:geos){
    geo.move();
  }

  GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
  gc.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
  for (GeometricObject geo:geos){
    geo.paintMeTo(gc);
  }
}
 };
  }
```

GeometricObject:

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;

public class GeometricObject {
Vertex corner;
double width;
double height;
Vertex velocity;

public GeometricObject(Vertex corner, double width, 
double height, Vertex velocity) {
super();
this.corner = corner;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.velocity = velocity;
}

double size(){
return width*height;
}

boolean isLargerThan(GeometricObject that){
return size()>that.size();
}
boolean isAbove(GeometricObject that){
return corner.y+height<that.corner.y;
}
boolean isUnderneath(GeometricObject that){
return that.isAbove(this);
}
boolean isLeftOf(GeometricObject that){
return corner.x+width<that.corner.x;
}
boolean isRightOf(GeometricObject that){
return that.isLeftOf(this);
}
boolean touches(GeometricObject that){
return !(isLeftOf(that)||isRightOf(that)
    ||isAbove(that)||isUnderneath(that));
}
void move(){
corner.move(velocity);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Geo("+corner+","+width+","+height+","+velocity+")";
}

public void paintMeTo(GraphicsContext gc) {    

gc.fillRect(3.2, 3.2, 3.2, 3.2);

//TODO.
//Paint the rectangle to the FX Graphics Content
}    
}
```

Vertex:

```
package name.panitz.oose.ws17;

public class Vertex {
double x;
double y;
public Vertex(double x, double y) {
super();
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}

void move(Vertex v){
x += v.x;
y += v.y;
}
void moveTo(Vertex v){
x = v.x;
y = v.y;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return "("+x+", "+y+")";
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
if (obj==null) return false;
if (!obj.getClass().equals(Vertex.class)) return false;
Vertex that = (Vertex)obj;
return (int)that.x==(int)this.x &&  (int)that.y==(int)this.y;
}  
}
```

Play:
    package name.panitz.oose.ws17;

```
public class Play extends Gapplication {
public Play() {
super(new GeometricObject(new Vertex(0, 0), 10, 10, new Vertex(0.2, 0.7)),
new GeometricObject(new Vertex(200, 150), 40, 80, new Vertex(0.1, 0.2))
);
}
}
```

Gapplication:

```
package name.panitz.oose.ws17;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Gapplication extends Application {  
Pane pane = new Pane();
Canvas canvas;
public Gapplication(GeometricObject... geos){
canvas =  new FXScreen(geos);
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
pane.getChildren().add(canvas);
Scene scene = new Scene(pane, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
}
}
```

Main:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource
("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

I am thankful for every kind of help.

Comment: I'm not Java developer, but you will have more luck finding an answer, if you ask clear questions. The question that I think you're trying to ask is; "How do I go about creating a basic JavaFX application". And that's a question that will definitely have an answer on Google. i.e. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/

Comment: Thats not really the Question I am trying to ask. The Problem is not reading a Tutorial. I had some of them ^^ The Problem is, my understanding of how JavaFX is working. I know that if I start an JavaFX Project, it would be easily done to do this work. But my exercise is to do it with the classes given to me. And that is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `Main` class and the `Gapplication` constructor. Then add a `main` method in Gapplication and initialize components in the `start()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gapplication.launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    pane = new Pane(); //Component initialization
    canvas =  new FXScreen(geos); //Component initialization
    pane.getChildren().add(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

And run Gapplication.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did the steps you recommended. But now there is an error in the start() method. the initialisation of canvas cant be done. 

In this line:

canvas =  new FXScreen(geos); //Component initialization

getting this error: "geos cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: The parameter `geos` is a `GeometricObject`  array, it is suposed to be initialized before the canvas.